# MYSQL and PHP database update wont update database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-update

I am having an issue trying update the database with a form.

So, my issue is when I click on update nothing happens. The database doesn't update.

Another issue is when i use POST in my form and SQL query. It doesn't pull the information through to the edit page, it is blank.

I'm sorry if this hard to read etc. but this is my first time posting. Also, I know there is security flaws in my GET/POST queries I'm just trying to get the thing to work before I start using the prepared statements or whatever they are called.

FYI, if I echo the query and define a if/else statement, I can see it doesn't work but I just don't know why. I have spent 3 days on this and change the code so many times using examples I have found on the internet.

> Index.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "****";

$link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");

if ($link->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";


mysqli_select_db($link,"jamesrph_myphp");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM article";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

$id = 'id';
$title = 'title';


?>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<title>PHP </title>

</head>

<body>

<h1> My title </h1> 

<table>

<tr> 
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

?>
<td><?php echo $row["title"]; ?> </td> 

<td><a href="article_detail.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Read More</a></td>

<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Edit</a></td>

</tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>       
</body>
</html>
```

> edit.php

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","******","******", "*****");

$query = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE id=".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['id'])." LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


$title = $row['title']; 

$content = $row['content'];

?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>      


<p> Edit Article </p>

<form method="get" action="processarticle.php">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" />

<input id="titlearea" type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>"/>    

<textarea id="contentarea" name="content" rows="10" cols="40"><?php echo $row["content"];?></textarea>    

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="update_article"/>

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

> processarticle.php

```
 <<?php
 //Database Connection
 include 'connection.php';
 //Get ID from Database
 if(isset($_GET['edit_id'])){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE id =" .$_GET['edit_id'];
 $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  }
 //Update Information
 if(isset($_POST['btn-update'])){
 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $content = $_POST['content'];
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $update = "UPDATE article SET title=?, content=? WHERE id=?";
 $up = mysqli_query($link, $update);

 if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($update)){
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi" ,$title ,$content ,$id);
    $stmt->excute();
 }
 header("location: disp.php");
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Try using concatenation (joining strings with a .) for the $title and $content aswell in the UPDATE query.

Comment: Sorry do mean in my links?

Comment: There's no value in getting something working and **then** fixing the security flaws. You'll have to learn to use prepared statements at some point anyway in order to fix it. Why not save time and learn the secure approach in the first place instead of learning how to make insecure code and then learning how to secure it afterwards?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: James, if you are where I was 3 years ago starting out writing flat php, the best thing you could do for yourself right now is start researching CMS, and if you want to be closer to the code then CMF. I personally like being close to the code so I use Symfony

Comment: @MattRaines thanks for the advice. Just i would have thought learning the easy things before going to more advance i.e secruity. Not disagreeing with you ofc but just would have thought that would be the process?.

Comment: It's a commonly held misconception that prepared statements are hard to learn. It isn't really any more advanced than what you are learning now.

Comment: @MattRaines ok fair do's I will look at them more closely then.

Comment: @MattRaines so i have been looking into this and updated my code. would tat be the correct way??

Comment: I'm not an expert on mysqli, I tend to use PDO. But it looks about right. You'd want to do the first query with `$_GET['edit_id']` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your edit.php form has a GET method, yet you are using POST variables in you processarticle.php and you have a GET variable in there.

Lets just say a form can only do one thing either GET or POST

The URL you specified in your form then will access either GET or POST variables based on form method

So if you want to update your article based off your form first lets look at the id = this should be $POST['id'] the hidden field in your form, not that hidden though

```
$update = "UPDATE article SET title='$title', content='$content' WHERE id=". $_POST['id'];
```

The more I look at this the more this is going to turn in to a 3 part mini series

Ok on your processarticle.php for starters I would use a prepared statement for the update http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

```
process.php

//Update Information
if(isset($_POST['Update_Article'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$SQL = "UPDATE
        article 
        SET title=?, content=?    
        WHERE id=?";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($SQL)) { 
     $stmt->bind_param("sss", $title ,$content ,$id );
     $stmt->execute();  
}
}
```

Start here http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp and go from crawling to walking
Honest to god work through that from top to bottom then go here 
https://symfony.com/ and hope in a F1 Car

Then try http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp because you are going to want your page to look cool

Comment: Thanks for the comment buddy. I will have a look at this and see if this is the issue. I will get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I have change all the get's to post's. It still doesn't work. Any other ideas? or is my code incorrect in general? the reason i had to have my form as GET rather than post is because if i used get the form will all populate the information from my database but if i use POST the form is blank and doesn't show my information.       have a look at this www.jamesrphayes.index.php and click edit the form is blank as i using post instead of get.

Comment: I got a response NULL

Comment: Ok I was going to make you 3 demo pages, but I started to and relised just how much work is involved with out using a framework, please please do the tuts and battle on with symfony

Comment: i have updated my code does that look good? I took your code as example. Hope you dont mind :)

Answer (score -1):

Use form method post or change all `$_POST` in `$_GET` in *processarticle.php*.
And try changing `$_GET['edit_id']` into `$_GET['id']` in *processarticle.php*.

Comment: POST would be the better way to do it, however it doesn't mean that you can't do it with GET